# how to Optimize query inside view

Tags: sql, join, query-optimization

I am having below query which is taking long time inside my view. I cant use indexes as it is view and i am using Select * statement in my views.

```
    SELECT  *
    FROM shell_v3 v3, 
    Shell_v41 v41, 
    core_demandsupply ds1,
    core_demandsupply ds2
    WHERE v41.profile_group = v3.profile_group
    AND v41.company = v3.company
    AND v41.product = v3.product
    AND v41.source_facility = ds2.facility
    AND v41.facility = ds1.facility
    AND case when ds1.reqd_date < getdate()
             then getdate()
             else ds1.reqd_date 
        end between v41.effective_Date and V41.Inactive_Date
```

Comment: Please post a schema and an EXPLAIN/execution plan

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use indexes? The view is still selecting from existing tables , so can add indexes on them .

Consider adding(if not exists) the following indexes:

```
shell_v3(profile_group,company,product)
Shell_v41(profile_group,company,product,source_facility,facility)
Shell_v41(facility,effective_Date,Inactive_Date)
core_demandsupply(facility,reqd_date)
```

This should improve your performance significantly.

Comment: Thanks but it is view so i cant use indexes and if i am going to use indexes for view i have to use schemabinding but again i am using select * statement and with schemabinding you cant use that.

Comment: Don't add indexes on the view! add them on the tables! This will affect the view! @ShaliniSinghRao

Comment: Shell_v3 and Shell_v41 both are views

Comment: Oh I see. Then follow this steps: `create  table as select from (the view)` , then add the proper indexes on them and then execute the select. Drop the table afterwards . You can do this many times if its needed on a daily basis. @shalinisinghrao